# Table Management Features by Creating Shapes and Drag-and-Drop in React.js

Tags: konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I am building an application in React.js that requires users to create and manipulate floorplans with detailed table management functionality. The features I need to implement include:

The features I need to implement include:

- Create a Floorplan: Allowing users to design and visualize different floors.
- Table Management: Enabling the following actions:

  - Add,Delete, and Edit Tables: This includes managing tables of different shapes like circles, squares, and ovals.
  - Select Number of Seats:Users should be able to specify the seating capacity of each table.
  - Labeling: I need to add labels to each table that show the timing and number of persons selected. Image Integration: I must provide an option for users to associate specific images with tables.  - Drag and Drop Functionality: Users should be able to drag and relocate tables within the floorplan
- Background and Table Image Management: I want to enable users to set background images for floors and specific images for tables.

Comment: First, welcome to SO. Second, this site is for solving problems, not asking 'how do I do something'.  We’re happy to help you, but in order to improve your chances of getting an answer, read up on these guidelines  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask